# Rails link_to nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I created a nested resources but my `link_to` shows `undefined method 'model_name' for Parking::ActiveRecord_Relation:Class` in the browser. I did it wrongly, obviously. How can I correct it?

index.rb

```
<%= link_to 'Create new parking', new_parking_path %></br>
<%= link_to 'Rent place', [@parking, @place_rent]%>
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :parkings do
    resources :place_rents, :only => [:new, :create]
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Either `@parking` or `@place_rent` is a relation (collection) and not a particular model which you would need to build a route. Depending on what is behind these variables you might need a `#first` or whole different query.